# What is my Google password?

Tags: password, google-account, password-protection

I set up my device quite some time ago and created a Google account. Since then, I haven't had to use my password even once because my device is linked to the account.

The problem is, now I would like to sign into my Google account online and I can't because I have absolutely no clue what my password is.

Is there any way I can recover or even change my password from my phone?

I understand the need for privacy but I really have no need for that kind of protection.

Comment: No, you can't recover the password nor you can change it using the device if you don't know the current password.  Passwords aren't saved in plain text in the device and there is no functionality in the Android to allow changing Google account password.

Comment: Did you try to go the account recovery page and tried to provide your mobile no, or email to recover your lost password?

Comment: @Lucky I haven't tried that yet, however, I don't have a phone number and don't even have a sim card.

Comment: @Firelord oh really, `/data/system/users/0/accounts.db` sqlite is plain text enough for me

Comment: You have an answer with the link to the account recovery page. Please try that and provide your email after selecting I don't know my password checkbox. You'll be shown the list of recovery options.

Comment: You still have your Android device, and I assume you're using Playstore from there. Recent versions of the Playstore app ask you to provide "alternative contact details" after each install/update. Provide them. Then you can get a new password sent there.

Comment: @izzy awesome I'll have to give that a try.

Comment: Good luck! And what I forgot to write: you're only asked as long as you didn't yet provide those details. Nasty nag-screen, I hate it (I don't like to give those details) – but can prove useful to some :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

visit https://www.google.com/accounts/recovery/ to recover password. you can do this from any browser. to create your own android "app password" you need to go to google.com/accounts/security and set an "app password"

however, if you need to recover anything ever again from your phone, you can enable the 2-step verification and verify your phone number so you can be texted stuff from google.

Comment: I don't have a phone number and don't use a sim card, I have wifi everywhere.

Comment: the website for google account recovery is accessable via wifi. so is the ability to make app passwords specifically /for/ your phone if you have 2-step verification. also, instead of text messages, android phones can instlal the "google authenticator" app... again, via wifi.

Comment: I will go ahead and accept this even though it wasn't exactly what I was looking for because it seems to be the only reasonable and most standard way to do this. However, I feel it needs to be said that this seems unacceptable from a user standpoint that the capability to manage my account etc. isn't at the very least an option for those of us who choose to take upon the responsibility of trading an extra layer of security for convenience. Certainly not that it should be a default, but that it should be an option, possibly with the same kind of warning we get when raising the volume too high.